# IE 6-7 pushing down floating div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have run into a problem whilst testing my website in IE7. I have got 2 containers that are suppose to float next to each other. It works fine in modern web browsers but in old versions of IE the right container is pushed under the left one. Can anyone see the problem? The main container is set to 1000px width. Here is the code for the 2 divs in question:

```
#content {
    width: 725px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    clear: both;
}

#SideBar {
    width: 225px;
    min-height: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 50px 25px;
}

    #SideBar img {
        display: table;
        margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
        border: 0;
    }
```

Here's the html:

```
<div id="PageWrapper">
<nav id="MainMenu">
</nav>
<header id="Header">
</header>
<section id="PageSlider">

<div id="content">

</div>
</section>
<aside id="SideBar">

</aside>
</div>
```

U can have a look at the website at [ashbaines.com](http://ashbaines.com)

The website is adapted to recognize html5 tags.

Thanks

Comment: Obvious first question to ask: Do you *really* still need to support IE6/7?

Comment: @Spudley - IE6 alone accounts for 5% worldwide (http://www.ie6countdown.com/), but that's mostly in China, so it might depend on your target market.

Comment: @user2906890 - if you set up a JsFiddle, perhaps people can have a play around themselves more easily?

Comment: Html 5 is not supported in  IE6/7.  I would recommend checking out the Modernizr.js library though, should solve a lot of compatability issues

Comment: just make sure ie6/ie7 users can see content, if something is not looking nice, you can ignore it. Of course you should fix major issues even on ie6/ie7.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with larger margins in the older IE versions. Try to set the floating elements to "display: inline;"

Here are some informations about this bug: 
http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html
http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Answer (score 0):

first change your code becuase you use `html5` tag like `nav`,`header`,`section`, and `aside` which is not suported by old browers like ie7, ie8.
so my suggestion to change your code and then try.

look at this code

```
<div id="PageWrapper">
  <div id="MainMenu">

  </div>
  <div id="Header">

  </div>
  <div id="PageSlider">
     <div id="content">

      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="SideBar">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used html5shiv to render the object for old web browsers but the problem still persists

Comment: your <aside> tag is outside of your <section> tag so put your <aside> tag into <section> tag after your content id div

Comment: and other solution is put your content id div outside <section> after <section> tag close. @user2906890